# Algorithm for the symbolic ordering of sums of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, symbolic-computation

Assume, there is a set of symbolic positive numbers in an ascending order (e.g., $a\leq b \leq c \leq d$). Is there a combinatorial algorithm that outputs all possible order relationships between $a, b, c, d$ and the sums of all possible subsets of this set, e.g.:

$a\leq b \leq a+b \leq c \leq a+c\leq \ldots \leq a+b+c+d$

Any hints or references are much appreciated. Many thanks and regards!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: After some searching, I came across this neat [algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89419/algorithm-wanted-enumerate-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-order-of-increasing-sums).