# How can i represent the terms of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I am having trouble representing this following list of numbers mathematically ,

$$ A_{n1}= (2*3) $$
$$=\color{red}{6}$$ 
$$ A_{n2} = (2*3)\, , (2*4)\, , (3*4)\, , (2*3*4) $$
$$= \color{red}{6,8,12,24} $$
$$ A_{n3} = (2*3),(2*4),(2*5),(3*4),(3*5),(4*5),(2*3*4),(2*3*5),(2*4*5),(3*4*5),(2*3*4*5) $$ 
$$ = \color{red}{6,8,10,12,15,20,24,30,40,60,120} $$
$$ A_{n4} = \begin{matrix} (2*3)&(2*3*4)&(2*3*4*5)&(2*3*4*5*6)\\ 
                           (2*4)&(2*3*5)&(2*3*4*6)\\
                           (2*5)&(2*3*6)&(2*3*5*6)\\
                           (2*6)&(2*4*5)&(2*4*5*6)\\
                           (3*4)&(2*4*6)&(3*4*5*6)\\
                           (3*5)&(2*5*6)&\\
                           (3*6)&(3*4*5)&\\
                           (4*5)&(3*4*6)&\\
                           (4*6)&(3*5*6)&\\
                           (5*6)&(4*5*6)&\\
\end{matrix}$$

$$ =\color{red}{6,8,10,12,12,15,18,20,24,24,30,30,36,40,48,60,60,72,90,120,120,144,180,240,360,720}$$

**Please note that the $A{n4}$ is not a matrix even though it resembles one (written as one) , i did it this way so that  you could see where the terms are coming from.

I have read on combinatorics , binomial theorem and others and still am having trouble.

My hopes are to represent each $A_{n}$ mathematically either as a sum , product or any kind of function where i can plug in a value and obtain a term perhaps such as :

$$ F(A_{nK},T)=F(A_{2},3) = (3*4) = 12 $$

This has stumped me for a few days.

I thank you kindly for your help and time with this problem.

Comment: I dont think there will be a general form for this as you are mentioning in the end, because series is fluctuating because of change in number of terms numbers being multiplied

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a nice way to write this down as a "closed formula". You are better off computing as-needed, or pre-computing and looking up as-needed, these values. See [Algorithm wanted: Enumerate all subsets of a set in order of increasing sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89419/318073), but instead of increasing sums, you want to have increasing products.

Comment: **If you are just intersted in stating this mathematically:** Let $\mathbb Z_{k}=\{0,1,2,\dots,k-1\}$. Then we can observe the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of this: Let $\mathcal P_m(\mathbb S)$ be the set of all subsets of some set $\mathbb S$, such that every subset has at least $m$ elements. Define the following [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset): (a set but duplicates are allowed) $$P_k=\left\{\prod_{s\in S}(s+2):S\in\mathcal P_2(\mathbb Z_{k+1}) \right\} $$ Define $F_k(n)$ as "function that returns the $n$*th* element of $P_k$, sorted by size" ?